# Spring Data Couchbase - connect to several nodes

Tags: couchbase, spring-data-couchbase

Java Couchbase client allows connecting to several nodes in a cluster (in case that one of them is not available)

Is is possible in Spring Data Couchbase?

I'm using Couchbase 2.1 and XML configuration for Spring

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can configure spring-data this way.  When you configure the CouchbaseClient using the CouchbaseFactoryBean, it accepts a comma-delimited list of hosts.  Here is an example of configuring the CouchbaseClient bean:

```
<couchbase:couchbase  bucket="myBucket" password="" host="host1,host2,host3"/>
```

This is assuming you are using the 1.4.x couchbase-client.jar dependency, which as long as you are using spring-data 1.1.5, you are fine.  You didn't specify your spring-data dependencies, but more than likely you should be good here.

Comment: it is also possible in Spring Data Couchbase 2.1, which uses the 2.2.x generation of SDKs

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this in spring data couchbase > 2.x is:

A cluster with three servers and three buckets each one with an user and a password.

```
<couchbase:cluster id="cluster_info" env-ref="couchbaseEnv2" >
    <couchbase:node>server1</couchbase:node>
    <couchbase:node>server2</couchbase:node>
    <couchbase:node>server3</couchbase:node>
</couchbase:cluster>

<couchbase:env id="couchbaseEnv2" connectTimeout="20000" computationPoolSize="10" />

<couchbase:clusterInfo cluster-ref="cluster_info" id="cluster1" login="user1" password="zzzzz1"/>
<couchbase:clusterInfo cluster-ref="cluster_info" id="cluster2" login="user2" password="zzzzz2"/>
<couchbase:clusterInfo cluster-ref="cluster_info" id="cluster3" login="user3" password="zzzzz3"/>

<couchbase:bucket id="bucket1" bucketName="user1" cluster-ref="cluster_info" bucketPassword="zzzzz1"/>
<couchbase:bucket id="bucket2" bucketName="user2" cluster-ref="cluster_info" bucketPassword="zzzzz2"/>
<couchbase:bucket id="bucket3" bucketName="user3" cluster-ref="cluster_info" bucketPassword="zzzzz3"/>

<couchbase:template id="couchBaseTemplate1" bucket-ref="bucket1" clusterInfo-ref="cluster1" />
<couchbase:template id="couchBaseTemplate2" bucket-ref="bucket2" clusterInfo-ref="cluster2"  />
<couchbase:template id="couchBaseTemplate3" bucket-ref="bucket3" clusterInfo-ref="cluster3"  />
```